# Moving turtle in turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

this is my code and I've been trying to make it move and I was wondering what I needed to do because I've tried everything and it made some error, this is my code i have tried a lot of the statements to make it move and it hasn't worked because one of the lines of code

```
import turtle as trtl
t = trtl.Turtle()
t.speed(100)
t.penup()
t.goto(0, -20)
t.pendown()
t.circle(100)
t.left(90)
t.forward(40)
t.penup()
t.forward(40)
t.pendown()
t.forward(40)
t.penup()
t.forward(40)
t.pendown()
t.forward(40)
t.right(180)
t.forward(40)
t.right(45)
t.right(45)
t.penup()
t.right(45)
t.goto(0, 140)
t.pendown()
t.left(203)
t.forward(46)
t.right(45)
t.forward(46)
t.right(45)
t.forward(46)
t.right(45)
t.forward(46)
t.right(45)
t.forward(46)
t.right(45)
t.forward(46)
t.right(45)
t.forward(46)
t.right(45)
t.forward(46)
t.right(45)
t.forward(46)
t.left(45)
t.forward(40)
t.penup()
t.goto(0, 140)
t.pendown()
t.left(180)
t.forward(46)
t.right(45)
t.forward(40)
t.penup()
t.right(180)
t.forward(40)
t.right(90)
t.forward(46)
t.right(45)
t.pendown()
t.forward(40)
wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.mainloop()
```

this code right here is with the def statement and the code that my friend told me to use so I can make it move a simple way but it throws out syntax errors directly on line 65 it wont spit it out properly

```
import turtle as trtl                   
t = trtl.Turtle()
        
Def moving_name(trtl):
    Screen = turtle.screen
    Screen.tracer
    import turtle as trtl
    t = trtl.Turtle()
    t.speed(100)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(0, -20)
    t.pendown()
    
    t.circle(100)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(40)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(40)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(40)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(45)
    t.right(45)
    t.penup()
    t.right(45)
    t.goto(0, 140)
    t.pendown()
    t.left(203)
    t.forward(46)
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(46)
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(46)
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(46)
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(46)
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(46)
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(46)
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(46)
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(46)
    t.left(45)
    t.forward(40)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(0, 140)
    t.pendown()
    t.left(180)
    t.forward(46)
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(40)
    t.penup()
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(46)
    t.right(45)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(40)
```

Comment: we will need more info on this. what error? what doesn't work specifically? and you should provide a [mre], there definitely is no need to have 50 of those function calls for us to reproduce the issue and I feel like the `Screen` should be initialized before moving the turtle

Comment: it gives me syntaxerrors and all of that when i put the movement statement

Comment: can you paste the errors it gives you for us?

Comment: can't reproduce any issues, it draws everything and there are no errors, besides, syntax errors are the basics to know how to fix but there aren't any in this code

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, your problem is these three commands:

```
t.goto(0, -20)
t.goto(0, 140)
t.goto(0, 140)
```

If we're going to be able to translate a turtle graphic cleanly, we need to define it with *relative* motion (e.g. `forward()`) not *absolute* motion to specific screen coordinates (e.g. `goto()`)

This is difficult to fix after the fact so you need to design your graphic with relative motion in mind.  Here's your code rewritten with relative motion and some logic to slide it across the screen:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def moving_name(turtle):
    start = turtle.position()
    heading = turtle.heading()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.left(68)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(8):
        turtle.forward(46)
        turtle.right(45)

    turtle.forward(46)
    turtle.left(45)
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.backward(40)
    turtle.right(45)
    turtle.backward(46)
    turtle.left(225)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(46)
    turtle.right(45)
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(46)
    turtle.right(45)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.setposition(start)
    turtle.setheading(heading)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.setx(-200)

for _ in range(20):
    turtle.clear()

    moving_name(turtle)

    screen.update()

    turtle.forward(10)

screen.tracer(True)
screen.mainloop()
```

This code saves and restores the turtle's position and heading but better designed code will naturally return the turtle to it's starting state  (e.g. like `circle()` does).

If we plan to rotate the graphic, then we also have to avoid absolute angles (e.g. `setheading()`) in preference to relative angles (e.g. `right()`).